# Parsing dates to a Rails friendly format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, formatting, date-format

I've got a batch of a 100k or so records that I'm importing to a Rails app.

There's a date in each row formatted like the following: `03/17/81`

However, when I try to just assign it to a date field, it gets converted as follows:

```
ruby-1.8.7-p174 > "03/17/81".to_date
 => Sat, 17 Mar 0081
```

Ultimately I would like the format to result in `1981-03-17`

Would this best be done on the import or should I be overriding in my Rails config to set the date standard to the format I need and what's the right approach in Rails 2.3.5?

Comment: How do you import these? You have http://apidock.com/ruby/Date/strptime/class

Comment: I have an import script that I'm running through script/runner and using FasterCSV to parse the data and simple ActiveRecord creates to insert the date.

Comment: Then definitely put your `strptime` in that script.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use

```
d = Date.strptime("03/17/81", "%m/%d/%y")
```

To get it out in 1981-03-17 use:

```
d.to_s
```

See [Date Rubydoc](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html).

Comment: Note that for dates before 1969, this will result in the incorrect century: `Date.strptime("12/31/68", "%m/%d/%y")` results in December 31, 2068.

Comment: Did you require 'date' in irb? Plus the %y is case sensitive, it has to be lower case, upper case means a 4 digit year.

Comment: Greg is completely correct. Depending on your data you may have to manually adjust those dates. The '-' operator will work with Date objects, so you can just subtract 100 years (if needed).

Comment: Ran against a few thousand records in my import and it seems to have handled all of the dates as expected.  No dates prior to 1969 so I think I'm in the clear in that regard.  Thanks for the quick snippet; I knew it would be trivial.

Comment: *blink* How did I never know about strptime?

Answer (score 3):

The proper way to do this, if you are going to reuse the format in multiple places is to do something like this: http://seanbehan.com/ruby-on-rails/custom-date-formats-for-your-rails-application/

Create a file `config/initializers/date_formats.rb`

...containing this:

```
ActiveSupport::CoreExtensions::Date::Conversions::DATE_FORMATS.merge!(
  :short_date => "%Y/%m/%d"
)
```

Then you should see:

```
ruby-1.8.7-p174 > date = "03/17/81".to_date
ruby-1.8.7-p174 > date.to_s(:short_date)
#=> "1981/03/17"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Chronic (gem install chronic):

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'chronic'
puts Chronic.parse "03/17/81"
#=> Tue Mar 17 12:00:00 -0800 1981
```

Returns a Time object.

Comment: Why should you install a Gem to perform a simple operation you can perform with a few lines of code?

Comment: Because once it's installed, it's only 2 lines. And it's *very* flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Don't change Rails, change your code.
I don't see any problem in creating a method that converts the string into a suitable date.

```
string = "03/17/81"
date   = if string =~ %r{(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)}
  Date.parse("19#{$3}-#{$1}-#{$2}")
else
  nil # failover
end
```

Comment: that was my first thought too :)

Comment: We're a decade into the 2000s.

Comment: @ Ben
Indeed, the code might need some changes. The question didn't set any requirement about 20xx dates.

Comment: So, why not use a library (gem) that has been written and tested to parse this and other formats? No need to reinvent wheels, etc.